# Page tracking using Webtrends v10

Tags: webtrends

How to track page views using WebTrend V10. I need to pass custom parameters using either WT, DCS or DCSext objects.I know Webtrends.multiTrack() method is used to track link click events. But any idea on how to do page view tracking.

Answer (score 0):

The data that Webtrends collects is attached to the objects as properties.  The properties are then iterated off the object to formulate the URL used to send the data.

You can add properties to the objects via `meta` tags.

```
<meta content="this/is/my/page" name="DCS.dcsuri" />
<meta content="The Title of this Page" name="WT.ti" />
```

You can do the same manually, but this is trickier, because the objects that need to be modified are not global.  The default WT object is `Webtrends.dcss.dcsobj_0.WT`.  If you are running the tag more than once, for captures to different accounts, then you would need to know which object `dcsobj_x` to update; e.g., `dcsobj_0` or `dcsobj_1` and so forth.

Obviously, `meta` tags are best in most cases.